# C++ Finding the mode with data from a text file, stored in a dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays, mode

I am having trouble finishing this function that finds the mode out of a list of ints. I am supposed to use pointers as arrays and pointer notation "*(arr + 1)" instead of arr[1] for example.
There is pseudocode provided by my instructor that explains the process for writing the function, but I am having trouble understanding certain parts. (sorry if this post is formatted poorly, this is my first post)

The complete program does a couple of other things, but I already managed to finish those functions without a problem

**The pseudocode is the following:**

```
int* calculateMode(int* movies, int size, int& numModes)
```

sort movies in ascending order

create dynamic array of ints called modes of size size

assign first int in movies to current

set counter to 1

set numModes to 1

set modePos to 0

set maxCount to 1

set first element in modes to current

for i = 1 to size

if *(movies + i) == current // same as current (previous one we looked at)

increment counter

if counter > maxCount // this means we have a new modePos

clear modes // need to clear any old modes in arrays, consider std::fill_n(modes, size, -1)

set modePos to 0 // start back at beginning of array for modes

set first element in modes to current // assign our new mode to beginning of array

set maxCounter to counter

set numModes to 1

else if counter == maxCount // got another mode

increment modePos // get the position for the next mode

assign current to next modePos in modes

increment numModes

else // we have a new current

assign movies value to current
et counter to 1

if counter == maxCount // if all values are represented once then they are all modes

increment modePos

assign current to modes and modePos

increment numModes

return modes

**The final output should be(with all the other functions):**

Total number of students who watched movies is 28
The average number of movies watched by all students is 27.46
The median number of movies watched by all students is 28.00
The mode number of movies watched by all students is 47, 16
Press any key to continue

**The text file is (where the first number "28" is the amount of numbers that there are in the file):**

28

14

16

19

6

9

47

43

28

35

16

30

6

47

12

14

47

41

16

44

22

20

31

45

34

31

44

4

8

**Here is my attempt**

```
int* calculateMode(int* movies, int size, int& numModes)
{

    sort(movies, movies + size);    //sorted movies array

    int* modes = new int[size]; //dynamic array of modes

    int current = *(movies + 0);    //the current mode (start on first number in array

    int counter = 1;    //how many of the same number there are

    numModes = 1;   //number of modes, the minimum always being 1

    int modePos = 0;    //position of the mode, 0 being the first number in array

    int maxCount = 1;   

    *(modes + 0) = current;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (*(movies + i) == current)   //same as current
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > maxCount) //new modePos
            {
                std::fill_n(modes, size, -1);   //clear modes
                modePos = 0;    //start back at beginning of the array for modes
                *(modes + 0) = current;
                maxCount = counter;
                numModes = 1;
            }
            else if (counter == maxCount) //got another mode
            {
                modePos++;  //get position for the next mode
                current = modePos;
                numModes++;
            }
        }
        else   //if we have new current
        {
            current = *(movies + i);
            counter = 1;
            if (counter == maxCount)    //if all values are represented once they are all modes
            {
                modePos++;
                current = modePos;
                numModes++;
            }
        }
    }   //end of for loop

    return modes;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, format properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I managed to make it work

```
int* calculateMode(int* movies, int size, int& numModes)
{
    sort(movies, movies + size);    //sorted movies array
    int* modes = new int[size]; //dynamic array of modes
    int current = *(movies + 0);    //the current mode (start on first number in array
    int counter = 1;    //how many of the same number there are
    numModes = 1;   //number of modes, the minimum always being 1
    int modePos = 0;    //position of the mode, 0 being the first number in array
    int maxCount = 1;



*(modes + 0) = current;

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (*(movies + i) == current)   //same as current
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter > maxCount) //new modePos
        {
            std::fill_n(modes, size, -1);   //clear modes
            modePos = 0;    //start back at beginning of the array for modes
            *(modes + 0) = current;
            maxCount = counter;
            numModes = 1;
        }
        else if (counter == maxCount) //got another mode
        {
            modePos++;  //get position for the next mode
            *(modes + modePos) = current; //here is where i made the change
            numModes++;
        }
    }
    else   //if we have new current
    {
        current = *(movies + i);
        counter = 1;
        if (counter == maxCount)    //if all values are represented once they are all modes
        {
            modePos++;
            *(modes + modePos) = current;    //here is where i made the change
            numModes++;
        }
    }
}   //end of for loop

return modes;
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, but a word of caution going forward. You do not want to *"managed to make it work"*. That implies [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (bad...). Instead, you want to fully understand the algorithm you are implementing and the language constructs that allow you to implement the algorithm in a reasonably efficient way. *Compile, fail, guess at changes, (repeat)...* -- is not programming -- it's guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can index a pointer array, so there is no need to iterate over it, with incrementing the first memory adress.
If you still wish to do it, OP2 is for you.

```
int calculateMode(int* movies, int size) {
    std::sort(movies, movies + size);
    /* OPT 1 */
    int number = movies[0], mode = movies[0], counter = 1, numModes = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (movies[i] == number) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            if (counter > numModes)
            {
                numModes = counter;
                mode = number;
            }
            counter = 1;
            number = movies[i];
        }
    }
    /* OPT 2 */
    number = *movies, mode = *movies, counter = 1, numModes = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(movies + i) == number) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            if (counter > numModes)
            {
                numModes = counter;
                mode = number;
            }
            counter = 1;
            number = *(movies + i);
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```